# Is wait_window() required for creating a modal dialog in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to create a modal dialog using Python Tkinter.  I found no difference between using and not using wait_window().

```
import tkinter as tk

def button_click():
  dlg = tk.Toplevel(master=window)

  tk.Button(dlg, text="Dismiss", command=dlg.destroy).pack()

  dlg.transient(window)    # only one window in the task bar
  dlg.grab_set()           # modal
  #window.wait_window(dlg) # why?

window = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(window, text="Click Me", command=button_click).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I've seen some examples in that use wait_window() for creating a modal dialog.  So I'm not sure whether the function is required for creating a modal dialog.

I'm using Python 3.5.

Comment: If you do not have a connection with anything in the main window, do not use. Otherwise you got  invalid path, invalid data, etc. errors. `grab_set` not equal to `wait_window`. `grab_set` not freezing main window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no, `wait_window()` is not required to make a modal dialog box. What makes a dialog modal is the grab that you put on the window.

Often, however, once the window is destroyed you may need to run some other code.  You can use `wait_window()` for this purpose, as it will wait for the window to be destroyed before continuing. You can then have code after that, such as a `return` statement, or some cleanup code. In your case there's nothing to do, so you don't need to call `wait_window`.

Answer (score 1):

running your code using `window.wait_window(dlg)` won't change anything as `dlg.grab_set()` already creates a modal dialog. this does only mean that you cannot close `window` while `dlg` is still alive. you cannot close window as the modal dialog grabs all mouse events from `window` and redirects them to `null`.

If you want to create a modal dialog without `grab_set()`, you would need to bind all mouse events to one handler and then decide if they should be allowed or dismissed **and** use `wait_window`.

As a modal dialog is defined by *"is anything outside the dialog **and** in my application available to be clicked"* == *False* , you already have a modal dialog only using `grab_set()`.

If your application shall not be able to programatically close `window`, you would need `wait_window()` as well.

Hope I made everything clear.